# How to convert curl to Angular 2, 4 or 5

Tags: angular, rest, curl, https

I try to connect my API with the following cURL, is there a way to convert this command to Angular 2, 4 or 5.

```
curl -k -i -X GET -H "Content-Type: application/json" -u username:"password" https://myRESTFULL_API_URL
```

I would try something like the code snipped bellow

```
getAPITest():Observable<any>{
const headers = new HttpHeaders({'Content-Type':'application/json; charset=utf-8','-u':'??????'});
return this.http.get('https://myRESTFULL_API_URL', {headers:headers})}
```

Any suggestions for a solution?

Comment: Your question is not clear ... what are you trying to achieve ? What is the signature of the function you want to write?

Answer (score 0):

You can replace -u with using the Authorization Header and basic authentication

```
Authorization: Basic EncodedValue
```

Where EncodedValue is base64 of the username:password string

So you can try that

```
const headers = new HttpHeaders(
{
    'Content-Type':'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    'Authorization':'Basic '+btoa(`${username}:${password}`)
});
```

where username and password are 2 variable containing the correct values